# How to create this toolbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

I am really having a hard time creating a `UIToolBar` programmatically(no xib file). This is what I would like to create.

But till now, I feel I have not approached it in the right way. I have tried adding a barbuttonitem to it, but I cant create the effect as shown in the png. How should I go about it. Help needed.

Edit: I have added a bigger image

Comment: Could you add a larger image? It's hard to see what we're actually looking at and what you're trying to accomplish. To me this looks like a UINavigationBar with a title set.

Comment: I tried adding barbuttonitem to the toolbar, but couldn't create the effect as shown in the image.

Comment: @Xavi Valero, I'm confused by your image, I see the nav bar at the bottom, but it looks like you are circling the table view. I'm not sure if that's what you intended but the part that is circled is a table view section in a Table View set to grouped.

Comment: @matto0...ignore the circled part. I just had this image to post. I am only concerned about the bottom bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"toolbar title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain    target:self     action:@selector(onToolbarTapped:)];
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem, customItem, spaceItem, nil];

[self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your toolbar with CGRECT to put it where you want

```
UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

You can customize it with background image, title, text color, background color, ...

Next create your button

```
UIBarButtonItem *theButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain    target:self     action:@selector(selector:)];
```

Add it to yout toolbar :

```
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: theButton, nil];
[myToolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO]
```

add your toolbar to the current view

```
[self.view addSubview:mytoolbar]
```

Just typed not tested, hope it'll help

Answer (score 1):

ToolBar and buttons have custom images

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, 320, 44)];
    [myToolbar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_40.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [self createImageButtonItemWithNoTitle:@"button_down.png" target:self action:@selector(closeMe:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonShare = [self createImageButtonItemWithNoTitle:@"button_share.png" target:self action:@selector(actionShareButton:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonFlexibleGap = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]autorelease];
    myToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonDone,barButtonFlexibleGap,barButtonShare,nil];

    [self.view addSubview:myToolbar];
    [myToolbar release];
}

-(void)closeMe:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"closeMe");
}

-(void)actionShareButton:(id)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"actionShareButton");
}

-(UIBarButtonItem *)createImageButtonItemWithNoTitle:(NSString *)imagePath target:(id)tgt action:(SEL)a
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_slice.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *buttonPressedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_slice_over.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0];

    CGRect buttonFrame = [button frame];
    buttonFrame.size.width = 32;
    buttonFrame.size.height = 32;
    [button setFrame:buttonFrame];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    [button addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonPressedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [button addTarget:tgt action:a forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return [buttonItem autorelease];

}
```

These png files need to be added

1. toolbar_40.png for toolbar image
2. button_down.png for button image
3. button_share.png for button image
4. button_slice.png  for button background
5. button_slice_over.png for button background (pressed)

Comment: I just need to create the toolbar as shown in the image. I don't have to add multiple barbuttonitems in the toolbar.

Comment: "[myToolbar insertSubview:[[[..." This Line of code is inserting a image on the toolbar. If your image (toolbar_40.png) has text on it and gradient (as shown in the image), you should get your desire toolbar.

Comment: Isn't there another way, than adding an image. I don't have an image that looks that matches the image shown

Comment: There should be another way I'll give you update on that...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Then add a `UIBarButtonItem` to `toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, 320, 44)];
myToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
myLabel.text = @"Sperre aufheben";
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[myToolbar  addSubview:myLabel];
[self.view addSubview:myToolbar];

[myLabel release];
[myToolbar release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a better fit for a nav bar (at least if you are keeping with the spirit of what you are doing: IE adding a title to the bottom of the screen)

Anyway I created a simple test project and this is what I did to get the functionality pictured, you may have to insert it into the view/controller differently but it gets what you want relatively easy and doesn't use the button bar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, 320, 44)];
    [navBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title"];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:title, nil];

    [navBar setItems:array];

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```