# UIToolbar creation

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

i have created a toolbar as below shown code and now i dont knw how to add the items to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];    
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];    
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 418, 350, 44);   
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init] autorelease]];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i'm not able to add the buttons to the tool bar.it is showing empty in the simulator

Comment: my question is how to add the buttons to this toolbar code?

Comment: im writing code without using the .nib files

Comment: Do a better reasearch on google and stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item"     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(action:)];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customItem, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

[customItem release];
```

You can also refer to this link:
[How to create this toolbar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500708/how-to-create-this-toolbar-programmaticallygle)

Please do google search and Stack Overflow search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

use
`[self setToolbarItems: buttons animated:NO];`
as u want to set toolbaritems and uiviewcontroller has toolbar itself.